# Shadow Dom Style in Vaadin Flow

Tags: css, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom, vaadin-flow

I've written a vaadin flow wrapper for [this polymer element](https://github.com/SimpleElements/simple-dropdown):

```
@Tag("simple-dropdown")
@HtmlImport("bower_components/simple-dropdown/simple-dropdown.html")
public class DropdownMenu extends Component implements HasComponents, HasSize, HasStyle {
    ...
}
```

This works. The documentation of `simple-dropdown` tells me I can style the shadow dom with this css:

```
simple-dropdown {
    --simple-dropdown-toggle: {
        justify-content: right;
    }
}
```

However, I'm unable to find the right place for this css in Vaadin flow. Where do I have to put it?

Comment: Based on vaadin docs you have few options: https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/theme/theming-crash-course.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webapp/frontend/styles/shared-styles.html

```
<custom-style>
    <style>
        simple-dropdown {
            --simple-dropdown-toggle: {
                justify-content: right;
            };
        }
    </style>
</custom-style>
```

Then, on the **toplevel layout** (not the flow wrapper!)

```
@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")
public class MainView extends Div {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use it where the parent's style, something like:

my-element.html

```
 <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html"> 
 <dom-module id='my-element'>
 <template>
    <style>
        :host {
          display:block;
        }
        simple-dropdown {
           --simple-dropdown-toggle: {
                  justify-content: right;
            }
        }

    </style>

    <simple-dropdown origin="top right" label="menu" arrow>
          <a href="#">item</a>
    </simple-dropdown>
 </template>
```

Comment: I tried to drop that file in my webapp/frontend folder, but nothing changed. I also tried adding `@HtmlImport("frontend/my-element.html")` to the class, but that didn't work either. How do I load your snippet?

Comment: I am not sure that I understood you. Do you have a polymer app yet. Or you just trying an element. If second, so here at this link there are many polymer samples: https://codepen.io/tony19/

Comment: This is not a polymer project. It is a vaadin flow project, which happens to be able to load polymer components.

Comment: I am sorry, i have no idea for vaadin flow.